# PHP 5.6, xDebug, Remote Debugging settings

Tags: php, xdebug, remote-debugging

Here's what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a remote server which has Xdebug, PHP-FPM (PHP 5.6), nginx, and has an external IP of x.x.x.x - I want to be able to connect to x.x.x.x:9000 from y.y.y.y for debugging purposes.

So, for this to happen, Xdebug has to listen on x.x.x.x - My question is how do I get Xdebug to bind to the x.x.x.x rather than localhost?

Here are the relevant portions of the xdebug.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=y.y.y.y
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
```

I hope I am clear.

Comment: `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` ...while the firewall might have `:9000` closed. in general, debugging on a remote host is a bad idea, unless it's located on the local network.

Comment: what port are you using for php-fpm ?  9000 by any chance ?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Firewall is open on port 9000 only for y.y.y.y

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote explains the options; maybe try `:9001` as remote port?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - Yikes! How could I have overlooked that?  Thanks.  However, the original question still stands - how to bind XDebug to the external port?  Or and I just thought of it: does the process only execute and listen when the app is running?  I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: @Jay Please clarify your last comment. Just in case: It's Xdebug that connects to editor/IDE and NOT other way around. Editor will (should) listen on ALL interfaces for incoming connections. How Xdebug connects to the editor (which interface to use) -- that's OS/network config thingy.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you - that clarifies it.

Comment: How the heck to I accept an answer?

Comment: @Jay There is nothing to accept -- no answers were created -- only comments. If your question was resolved -- consider writing your own answer and accept it later (a day or two) -- it will help others in similar situation.